# VB.NET - Scroll to bottom of WebBrowser Control after DocumentText Update

Tags: vb.net

So i have looked at several other posts on stackoverflow and none of them seem to be working for me to accomplish this. All I want to do is for the WebBrowser control to automatically scroll down to the very bottom after I change something programmatically in the webbrowser1.documenttext property.

I've tried ALL of the following ways, and none of them work... I actually have them literally all in the exact same line of code.

```
     WebBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = True
    WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollIntoView(False)

    WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(New Point(WebBrowser1.Height, WebBrowser1.Height))



    WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(WebBrowser1.Height, WebBrowser1.Height)
    WebBrowser1.AutoScrollOffset = New Point(WebBrowser1.Height, WebBrowser1.Height)
```

In my WebBrowser1 control all I have done is set started it with  and then at the end placed  and in the middle all i've done is copied 'n pasted the following...

```
    <html><body>
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   <div style="color: red;">blah blah</div><Br />
   </body></html>
```

about 30 times... BUT I can't get anything to work. None of the code above is doing anything.

What am I missing?

VS 2005 SP1 - VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be you are trying to access the DOM before it is updated.  Fire your code to scroll the correct element into view in the DocumentCompleted event, like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = <html><body>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;'>blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   <div style='color: red;' id="lastElement">blah blah</div><Br/>
                                   </body></html>.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim lastGuy= WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("lastElement")
    If lastGuy<> Nothing Then
        lastGuy.ScrollIntoView(True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: that code you posted throws an error. I even replaced "input" with "div" and set a div name for each div to "blah" and replaced your "q" with "blah" and i get an error - "Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1. Parameter name: index"... Keep in mind thou i'm not nagivating to any webpage at all.

Comment: I tested your code, the only reason why your code works is because its using an input box.

Comment: @eqiz I updated the answer to reflect how it should work in a scenario where you load the documenttext.

Comment: in my instance i just created an ID with an integer and kept increasing it by 1 to get the last one. It works, thanks for the in-depth explaination.

Comment: its actually not working for me. The document with the text loads, but documentcompleted or something doesn't trigger for some reason and it doesn't scroll to the bottom.

Comment: the only way i got the documentcompleted code to even work is putting it in a button and manually clicking it after the document text gets set.. which doesn't make sense to me? because I should be able to just put that code directly after the code that sets the DocumenText, but that doesn't work either. I even tried making it wait until WebBrowser1.IsBusy = False

Comment: Is the document completed event wired up to the webbrowser control correctly?  Delete any document completed events and go back into the `Events` section under properties and recreate the event.

Comment: Wow... i feel like an idiot. It wasn't handling the event for some reason. Must been from all the changes I kept constantly doing. Wow, thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

```
wb1.Navigate("javascript:window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
```