# How do you set focus on a particular webpage element? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, scroll, focus

Say for example this is my html document.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1">
</div>
<div id="2">
</div>
<div id="3">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How in VB.net would would i set the webrowser control to scroll automatically or focus on a specific element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML ID and Class names can't begin with a digit, so `id="1"` is invalid.

What happens with the page after it is rendered is the web browser's business. VB.Net is server side code, so you're better off using JavaScript.

```
    <body onLoad='document.getElementById("myDiv1").focus();'>
```

---

After reading a little more closely, I see you specified scrolling in a WebBrowser control. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307345/242584).